# Pass a pipe FILE content to unknown size char * (dynamic allocated)

Tags: c

I have a `FILE *` from a pipe (popen), and I wanna pass it to `char *artist`.
The size of information that will be in the FILE is unknown, so it should use `malloc()`.

```
FILE *tmp1;
char *artist;
tmp1 = popen("cmus-remote -Q | grep 'tag artist' | sed s/'tag artist'/''/g | sed '1s/^.//'", "r");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See also [`char *` being different when coming from a FILE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026107/char-being-different-when-coming-from-a-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to use a temporary buffer to read chunks in and attach them to the artist as  following:

```
char buf[8192];
char *artist = NULL;
size_t len = 0, total_len = 0;
FILE *fp;

fp = popen("cmus-remote -Q | grep 'tag artist' | sed s/'tag artist'/''/g | sed '1s/^.//'", "r");

while (!feof(fp)) {
      if ( fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) == NULL ) 
             break;
      len = strlen(buf);
      artist = realloc(artist, len+1); /* +1 for \0 */
      if (artist == NULL) {
             fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of memory\n");
             exit(-1);
      }
      strncpy(artist+total_len, buf, len+1); /* concatenate the string at the end of artist */ 
      total_len += len;
}
```

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: @HenriqueLengler no, this way keeps going until the system cannot expand a logically contiguous allocation.  On a modern system with virtual memory, contiguity should not be an issue, since any free physical page can be mapped to the next logical address.  I'll admit I might be tempted to process in an implementation page size, but that's often 4096 and 8192 is a nice multiple.  It would get risky on a system without virtual memory though!

Comment: So I wrote this code and compiled it.
There is a problem, everything works fine but when it reach total_len += len; the char become duplicated. e.g Smog\n turns in Smog\nSmog\n.

Comment: @Ahmed Masud Any tip?

Comment: Fixed using fgets to control the loop. @JonathanLeffler are right




while (!feof(file)) is wrong.

Comment: Replace the `strncpy()` with either `strncpy(artist + total_len, buf, len + 1)` or `memmove(artist + total_len, buf, len + 1)` (or you can use `memcpy()` instead of `memmove()` in this context, but don't change to `memcpy()` unless you know why it is safe now and when it is unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this on a machine with POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is:

```
char *buffer = 0;
size_t bufsiz = 0;
ssize_t nbytes;

FILE *tmp1 = popen("cmus-remote -Q | sed -n '/tag artist./ { s/tag artist//g; s/^.//p; }'", "r");
if (tmp1 == 0)
    …report problem and do not use tmp1…

while ((nbytes = getline(tmp1, &buffer, &size)) > 0)
{
    …process line of data…
}
free(buffer);
```

This limits your lines to the size of the allocatable memory; this is seldom a real limitation.  Note that you only need a single `sed` command to process the output of `cmus-remote`.